# Can't access Rails Production Console on VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, console

I have setup my rails app on linode and the website is working as expected. I tried to access the Rails Console after "ssh"ing in my console, but I am getting the following errors (note I am running the commands from my apps main directory):

```
~/apps/my_app$ bundle exec rails c production - Could not locate Gemfile

~/apps/my_app$ RAILS_ENV=production rails console -bash: /usr/bin/rails: No such file or directory

~/apps/my_app$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c - Could not locate Gemfile
```

I have Ruby 1.9.3 installed and in my gemfile I have: `gem 'rails', '3.2.9'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says you are missing the Gemfile. Ensure from the output of `ls` command (from where you are eg. `~/apps/my_app`) that `Gemfile` is here. My guess is either you are not in the right directory, either the Gemfile has not been deployed to your repository.

Comment: Got it. So you have to run the command from the directory of the Gemfile. Had to go to `~/apps/my_app/current` and then `bundle exec rails c production` worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yes `bundle exec` expects you to be in the root of you rails application. Glad it helps